# cssJanus stop inverting to rtl

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am using [cssjanus](https://cssjanus.github.io/) to convert rtl and ltr.

I want cssJanus not to convert for certain cases, i.e `ltr` should remain `ltr`.

How to escape CssJanus to stop converting `ltr` to `rtl` in here:

```
td.price {
     direction: ltr !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried placing an inline rule on the element? cssJanus will rewrite the css rules, ignoring the `!important` basically (I think) but inline rules might stay. Make sure you remove the current rule first!

Or you could use the built in no-flip exception:

```
/* @noflip */ .ignored { direction: ltr; }
```

Then I believe you could simply add the `ignored` class to the element, like this:

```
<td class="price ignored">...</td>
```

Hope that helps :-)